# How to fetch select box selected option value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Please help me to solve my issue.

I have following code.
this my html code.

users.php

```
<select id="user_position"  name="user_position">
    <option value="0">Select Position</option>
    <option value="1">Management</option>
    <option value="2">Rekeyer</option>
    <option value="3">Assistant</option>
    <option value="4">Macro Specialist</option>
    <option value="5">Template Engineer</option>
    <option value="6">Support</option>
</select>

<a onclick="javascript:createposition()" style="margin-top: 9px; display: inline-block;" href="javascript:void(0);">Create user position</a>
```

my jquery code

users.js

```
function createposition() {
    console.log($("#user_position option:selected").val());//it return option text insted of value.
    if ($("#user_position").val() == "") {
        alert("Please select user position.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `valule` correct the spelling `value`

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c9pjcs4o/) your code works. only misspelled word

Answer (score 2):

You need to use attribute `value` instead of `valule`:

```
 <option value="0">Select Position</option>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gqtmq58o/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
function createposition() {
   console.log($("#user_position").val());//it return option text insted of value.
   if ($("#user_position").val() == 0) {
      alert("Please select user position.");
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You code block works fine, just need to correct the attribute name.

**valule** to **value** at:

```
<option **valule**="0">Select Position</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `valule` to `value` in your option list

AND change

`console.log($("#user_position").val());`

instead of

```
console.log($("#user_position option:selected").val());
```